# what is the use of webapp-cache.xml?

Tags: maven

what is the use of webapp-cache.xml? Does it cache any data like images, htmls etc..?? I can see that it gets created after maven build, however I could not understand the importance of this `webapp-cache.xml`.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from the [Maven WAR Plugin Docs](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/inplace-mojo.html#cacheFile)

```
cacheFile:

The file containing the webapp structure cache.
Type: java.io.File
Since: 2.1-alpha-1
Required: Yes
Default: ${project.build.directory}/war/work/webapp-cache.xml
```

The WAR plugin uses this file in the process of creating the WAR file.

Comment: +1 and... is there an equivalent to `cacheFile` in **maven-compiler-plugin** or **build-helper-maven-plugin**?

Comment: It's not clear why you would want to enable or disable the cache feature.